# appJar Internationalisation not working

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, internationalization

I am trying to use [appJar](http://appjar.info)'s [internationalisation](http://appjar.info/pythonInternationalisation/) feature with English and Spanish. However, when I use the English config file, everything works fine, but when I use Spanish one, I get errors. When the file is encoded in ANSI, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I have also tried to encode it in UTF-8, but again, I get an error:

```
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'SPANISH.ini', line: 1
'\ufeff[TABBEDFRAME]\r\n'
```

The English config file is exactly the same as the Spanish one - the only difference being the translation.

I would be grateful for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example (a python script and both of ini files), so an anybody interested can represent your problem? They're shouldn't be so long, if gui has only several widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Spanish config file seemed to be corrupted - when I copied the contents over to a new file, it worked fine.